# Pushing values into Mongodb model in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mean

HI I am using `MEAN stack` with two data models that are interrelated:

Post and Comment

So in my `PostSchema` I have

```
comments:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Comment'
```

and in my `CommentSchema` I have

```
post:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Post'
    }
```

After I input a comment in my view I want the backend to save the comment in the Comment collection and also save the comment in the Post collection.

In my server app.js file:

```
comment.save(function(err,comment){
        if(err){return next(err);}
        var post = new Post(req.post)
        post.comments.push(comment)
       // OR req.post.comments.push(comment);etc
        post.save(function(err,post){
            if(err){return next(err);}

            res.json(comment);
        })
    })
```

However, where I use `post.comments.push` or `req.post.comments.push`, I get an error message on command line that `push is not a function`.

The above code is from an online tutorial[1] . I searched the net but cant find any similar example of `push` being used.

Can you please let me know if I have been misled with `push` and if there is another way that I should be doing this?

[1]https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#wiring-everything-up

Comment: The error means `post.comments` is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not define ARRAY of comments, but only one (standard) comment, therefore it is not array and it does not have "push" method. The definition should look like this :

```
comments:[{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Comment'}]
```